# How to view all special characters

Tags: unix, sed, awk, special-characters

I am facing hard time in removing the special characters from the csv file.
I have done a head -1 so i am trying to compare only 1 row.
wc filename shows it has 1396 byte count
If i go to the end of the file the curson ends at 1394.
In vi I do set list (to check for control characters), i see a $ (nothing after that), so i now know its the 1395 byte count.
Can someone please tell me where is the 1396th byte?
I am trying to compare 2 files using diff and its giving me a lot of trouble.
Please help.

Comment: Have you tried [`od`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?od)?

Comment: If you run `dos2unix` on your file, does it change anything? ie `dos2unix myfile > tmpfile; diff myfile tmpfile`

Comment: No. how can i use that to get the last byte?

Comment: It does. Just ran dos2unix and the bytecount is now 1395.
So does that mean the 1396 byte was not being recognised by Unix?

Comment: The daily `dos2unix` question ;-/ . Good luck to all.

Comment: @Josh - 'dos2unix myfile > tmpfile' is actually creating a blank tmpfile, but it does convert myfile to Unix format.

Comment: @shellter "daily"? If only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last 2 bytes of your line are `\r\n` - this is a Windows line ending. `dos2unix` converts this into a Unix line ending, which is `\n` - hence the line is shortened by 1 byte following conversion.